# Generating electromagnetic signal using CPU clock

Tags: rf-electronics, computer-hardware

Laptops have processors running on few GHz clock. Is there a way to generate electromagnetic signals in that range using some software or coding? Say generating 2.4 GHz signal if the CPU runs at 3 GHz.

Comment: This question is too broad. If you have a more specific question or can give more details about what you're trying to do, that would help a lot